# how can i combine multiple pdf to convert single pdf in android?

Tags: android, pdf, merge

I have single page several PDF files in my SD card. Now I need to programmatically merge those single page PDF files in to one PDF document. I have used Android PDF Writer library to create those single PDF files. How can I do that?I tried some codes and questions but i cant find any good answer.
Can anyone please help me out ?

Comment: if you are able to read each pdf with that library again then you may generate new pdf using same library and add all pages in it.

Comment: i tried but nothing there to help me.can you suggest any other libraries or some codes to help me out ?

Comment: post some code and let me know what exactly you are facing while implementing above approach

Comment: i don't have any codes to post. Actually am looking for some.can anyone show me some ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this for APW (Android PDF Writer), but you can combine multiple PDF Files on Android with with the latest [Apache PdfBox Release](https://pdfbox.apache.org). (At the moment still not final... RC3...)

Just add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.0-RC3'
```

And in an async task do this:

```
private File downloadAndCombinePDFs(String urlToPdf1, String urlToPdf2, String urlToPdf3 ) throws IOException {

    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
    ut.addSource(NetworkUtils.downloadFile(urlToPdf1, 20));
    ut.addSource(NetworkUtils.downloadFile(urlToPdf2, 20));
    ut.addSource(NetworkUtils.downloadFile(urlToPdf3, 20));

    final File file = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");

   final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        ut.setDestinationStream(fileOutputStream);
        ut.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

    } finally {
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Here NetworkUtils.downloadFile() should return an InputStream. 
If you have them on your sdcard you can open a FileInputStream.

I download the PDFs from the internet like this:

```
public static InputStream downloadFileThrowing(String url, int timeOutInSeconds) throws IOException {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful())
        throw new IOException("Download not successful.response:" + response);
    else
        return response.body().byteStream();
}
```

To use the OkHttpClient add this to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
```

Comment: For Android use port: https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android