# How to merge multiple pdf file into single in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdf, merge

How to read **multiple** .pdf files from the device and merge them into **single** .pdf file in Android Studio?

Comment: Check this open-source project try run build-run in your android studio https://github.com/SuicSoft/Little-PDF-Merge-Android

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737118/how-can-i-combine-multiple-pdf-to-convert-single-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 2):

For more than 2 pdf files merge into single document use  Apache PdfBox.

1. Add pdfBox dependency  api 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.0-RC3'
2. Add following code
3. Create a list containing the pdf file paths you want to merge into single.

   val merger = PDFMergerUtility()

   ```
                   for (path in pathList) {
                       merger.addSource(path)
                   }
                   val p = savePath +"/${documentsModel.fileName}.pdf"

                   val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(p)
                   try {

                       merger.destinationStream = fileOutputStream

                       merger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())
                   } finally {
                       fileOutputStream.close()
                   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge 2 pdf files into single document using iText Pdf with the Kernal packages.

1. Add iText dependency api 'com.itextpdf:kernel:7.1.9'
2. add following code

```
    val p = savePath + "/merged.pdf"
                            val pdfDocument: PdfDocument = PdfDocument(
                                PdfReader(path1),
                                PdfWriter(p)
                            )
                            val pdfDocument2: PdfDocument = PdfDocument(PdfReader(path2))
                            val merger = PdfMerger(pdfDocument)
                            merger.merge(pdfDocument2, 1, pdfDocument2.numberOfPages)
                            pdfDocument2.close()
                            pdfDocument.close()
```

[you can see the documentation and code for merging](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/merge-pdf-files-for-free-online)